# MLE of Geometric distribution - consistency and variance of inverse arithmetic sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I want to calculate the MLE and its consistency of Geometric distribution:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$$

$$
l(p) = p(1-p)^{x_1-1}\cdot p(1-p)^{x_2-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot p(1-p)^{x_n-1} \\
L(p)=n\ln p + (x_1 + \cdots +x_n -n)\ln(1-p) \\
(L(p))'= \frac{n}{p} - \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n - n}{1-p} \\
\hat{p} = \frac{n}{x_1 + \cdots + x_n} = \frac{1}{\overline{X}}
$$

Now, to check the consistency I would use Markov's Inequality:

$$
\mathbb{P}(|\hat{p_n} - \mathbb{E}(\hat{p_n})| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\hat{p_n})}{\epsilon^2}
$$

I am stuck on calculating Variance though. Variance of arithmetic sum would be a breeze - here though it is an inverse of it. How can i proceed? Is it just the inverse of $\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X})$ = $\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{n}$ which would equal $\frac{n}{\operatorname{Var}(X)}$? What is the $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p_n})$?

Comment: What about the expected value of $\hat{p_n}$? I need to check if it equals $p_n$

Comment: No there is no such condition.

Comment: For consistency not, but I also want to see if the estimator is biased or not and I need the $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p_n})$ for that.

Comment: You can use Jensen's inequality to prove it is biased.

Comment: Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Parameter_estimation) on parameter estimation for two versions of geometric distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a general fact that maximum likelihood estimators are consistent under some regularity conditions. In particular these conditions hold here because the distribution of $X$ is a member of a regular exponential family. Some discussion can be found in [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf) lecture notes, but you can also find these results on a textbook covering asymptotic theory.

Consistency can be justified from the law of large numbers, which says

$$\overline X \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \operatorname E\,[X_1]=\frac1p$$

By [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), this implies

$$\frac1{\overline X} \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow p$$

Alternatively, you can use a [Taylor expansion on moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) to say that $\operatorname E\left[\frac1{\overline X}\right]\approx p$ and $\operatorname{Var}\left[\frac1{\overline X}\right]\approx \frac{p^2(1-p)}{n}$ for large $n$, so that $\operatorname E\left[\frac1{\overline X}\right]\to p$ and  $\operatorname{Var}\left[\frac1{\overline X}\right]\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. This is a sufficient condition for convergence in probability.

Comment: From the section on *asymptotic normality of MLE* in the linked notes, one can also find the asymptotic variance of MLE as the inverse of Fisher information in a single observation.

Comment: So the conclusion will be Estimator is biased but consistent, right?

Comment: @ShivTavker Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one may compute the expectation of $\hat{p}_n$. Let $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $S_n-n\sim \text{NB}(n,1-p)$ ([negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)) and the expectation of $\hat{p}_n$ takes the following form:
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\hat{p}_n&= \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{n}{k+n}\binom{k+n-1}{k}(1-p)^k p^n \\
&= p\cdot{}_2F_1(1,1;n+1;1-p),
\end{align}
where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html). Since
$$
{}_2F_1(1,1;n+1;1-p)=n\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{1-x(1-p)}\,dx,
$$
it follows that for $p\in (0,1)$,
$$
p< \mathsf{E}\hat{p}_n< \frac{p}{1-n^{-1}}.
$$

That is $\hat{p}_n$ is asymptotically unbiased, i.e., $\mathsf{E}\hat{p}_n\to p$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

MLE of $p$ for Geometric Distribution is biased. You can use Jensen's Inequality to show this:
$$\
E(\frac{1}{\overline{X}}) > \frac{1}{E(\overline{X})} > \frac{np}{n} > p
$$
Note that $\frac{1}{x}$ is a strictly convex function for $x \in (0, c)$ where $c$ is a constant which is bounded wagely, $c < \infty$. Hence, we can have strong inequality ($<$ instead of $\leq$). To compute the exact value you can use the fact that sum of n i.i.d Geometric r.vs follows Negative Binomial Distribution. Hence,
$$\
E(\frac{1}{\overline{X}}) = nE(\frac{1}{Y}) \text{ where, } Y \sim NegBin
$$
For consistency you can proceed like this:
$$\
P(|\frac{1}{\overline{X}}-p|\leq\epsilon)=P(\frac{1}{\epsilon +p} \leq \overline{X} \leq \frac{1}{p-\epsilon}) = P(\frac{n}{\epsilon +p} \leq Y \leq \frac{n}{p-\epsilon})\\ \text{ where, } Y \sim NegBin
$$
You can compute the above and check consistency. I guess it will turn out to be consistent.
**Edit:** It turns out the cdf of Negative Binomial Distribution is not straight forward to solve. We need to use some inequality.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks have made that change.

Answer (score -1):

A brief simulation in R will illustrate some of the issues
you need to consider. R uses a version of the geometric
distribution taking values $0, 1, 2, \dots.$ Your version
takes values $1, 2, 3, \dots,$ hence the $+1$ in the R code
to illustrate your version.

Let $n=10, p = 0.3:$

```
set.seed(329);  n = 10;  p = .3
a = replicate(10^6, mean(rgeom(n, p)+1))  # averages of 10 obs
mean(a);  var(a)        
[1] 3.334036              # aprx 1/p = 1/.3 
[1] 0.7815287             # aprx (.7/.3^2)/10 = .7778
```

The MLE is $\hat p_n = 1/\bar X,$ as you say. However, it is clearly *not* unbiased. (With a million iterations, we should get about
two place accuracy.)

```
p.est = 1/a
mean(p.est);  var(p.est)
[1] 0.3217807             # NOT aprx 0.3
[1] 0.007767821
```

Estimation of $p$ is an important problem for some medical applications, and it is not trivial. Wikipedia moves quickly to a discussion of Bayesian approaches. You can google to access
a few scholarly papers on the estimation of geometric $p$ that are
not behind pay walls.